# Comma appears in front of last typed word in IBus Pinyin input method

Tags: keyboard, language-support, ibus, chinese, pinyin

I'm using the IBus Chinese "Intelligent" Pinyin input method to enter Chinese characters. However, I noticed a problem when entering punctuation: While entering a Chinese word and NOT pressing space afterwards, but a punctuation character (such as comma or dot), the punctuation character appears *in front of* the last typed word. Example:

[image: Illustration of the problem: I typed "标点", then "，", but the comma appears in front of "标点"]

In this example, I first entered "我输入", then hit space, then entered "标点", then "，". This caused the comma to appear in front of "标点", which is quite unexpected. Is there a way to solve this by configuration or is it a bug?

Comment: Maybe try the *Chinese (Intelligent Pinyin)* method (the `ibus-libpinyin` package) and see if it behaves more like you expect.

Comment: That's the one I'm currently using. I edited my question accordingly.